# sha256(new Buffer(string, 'hex')) in python

Tags: python, node.js

Currently I have this code written in nodejs.

```
const sha256 = require('js-sha256').sha256;
var stringl = "8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc68198f3470a7388c05ee4e7af3d01d8c722b0ff5237400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c4b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e240"
console.log(sha256(new Buffer(stringl, 'hex')));
```

it returns

```
2c0a99a5727be633e440dd8ce2090a0ab7d5a84ccafc9385ea9812db4d715df1
```

I want to convert the code from nodejs to python (3.5) .

I thought I could just do it with this code.

```
import hashlib
string21 = "8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc68198f3470a7388c05ee4e7af3d01d8c722b0ff5237400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c4b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e240"
print(hashlib.sha256(str(int(string21,16)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

but that returns

```
346c61765546d4ff12fdbea997f40bdb5216b8df2b5402a6b45893df723132f6
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Look at what `str(int(string21,16))` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Buffer` returns an array of bytes (integers in `range(0, 256)`), so you need to do the same thing in Python:

```
print(hashlib.sha256(bytearray.fromhex(string21)).hexdigest())
```

`bytearray.fromhex` does exactly what it says: creates a `bytearray` from a hexadecimal representation.

EDIT: there's no need to `encode` anything here as `bytearray`s already represent bytes.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you so much!